# Validar registro MySQL al ingresarlo en Form PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, php7

Tengo esta interfaz pequeña que valida selecciones de un selectbox y redirije a la página correspondiente (son 4 diferentes de acorde a las selecciones), pero antes de ello hay una caja de texto para ingresar un pin que se enviará a la caja de texto de la página seleccionada. Esto ya funciona pero lo que necesito es validar que este pin exista en la BDD de mysql y no logro hacerlo.
Agradecería su ayuda, este es mi código.

Form:

```
<form action="validar.php">
<label>PIN</label>
<input name="pinWrite">
<br>
<label>Te gusta el Cine? </label>
<select name='Uno'>
       <option value='si' id="si1" name="si">SI</option>
       <option value='no' id="no0" name="no">NO</option>
</select>

<label>Te gusta leer? </label>
<select name='Dos'>
       <option value='si' id="si11" name="si">SI</option>
       <option value='no' id="no00" name="no">NO</option>
</select>
<button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

validar.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$selectBox1 = $_POST["Uno"]; 
$selectBox2 = $_POST["Dos"];
$pin_obtenido = $_POST['pinWrite'];
$_SESSION['pin_guardado'] = $_POST['pinWrite'];

require_once 'conexion.php';
$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE 
pin = '$pinWrite'");

if(!$consulta){

if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
header('Location: pag1.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: pag2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: pag3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: pag4.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: index.php');
} 
}else{
echo 'PIN INCORRECTO';
}
?>
```

Comment: La variable que usas en la consulta: `"SELECT * FROM registros WHERE 
pin = '$pinWrite'"` no existe, si observas bien, el valor de asigna a otra variable: `$pin_obtenido = $_POST['pinWrite'];` Lo más simple es que cambies el nombre de esa variable: `$pinWrite = $_POST['pinWrite'];`  o que modifiques el `SELECT`... Luego, esta validación tampoco es segura: `if(!$consulta){` ya que `query` devuelve `true` aunque no haya filas. Lo correcto aquí es hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM...` y luego comprobar si `total > 0` para saber si el criterio se cumple. Hay por tanto errores de lógica.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ya he podido resolverlo de la forma que esta abajo. SALUDOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido encontrar la solución de la siguiente forma:

validar.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $selectBox1 = $_POST["Uno"]; 
 $selectBox2 = $_POST["Dos"];
 $pin_obtenido = $_POST['pinWrite'];
 $_SESSION['pin_guardado'] = $_POST['pinWrite'];

 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE pin = '$pin_obtenido'";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

 $filas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

 if($filas>0){

 if ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "si") {
 header('Location: pag1.php');
 }
 elseif ($selectBox1 == "si"  && $selectBox2 == "no") {
header('Location: pag2.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "no"){
header('Location: pag3.php');
}
elseif ($selectBox1 == "no"  && $selectBox2 == "si"){
header('Location: pag4.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: index.php');
} 
}else {
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("EL PIN ES INCORRECTO");
window.location.href="index.php";
</script>';
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```